# PHP Echo Inside Javascript String

Tags: javascript, php

I want to be able to echo a PHP link inside a JavaScript string, i.e. `<?php echo SITE_URL ?>`. How can I do this with the code below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.backstretch("http://www.example.com/bg.jpg");
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.backstretch('<?php echo str_replace(array("\\", "'"), array("\\\\", "\\'"), SITE_URL); ?>');
</script>
```

I also made sure to escape `'` and `\` to avoid any problems.

Comment: If I'd like to add a folder like `img/bg.jpg`, can I simply continue after the echo? It works great btw, thank you.

Comment: @user2442178 Yes. Either continue after the `echo` or use string concatenation in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
<script>

var test= '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>';// and use it as you please
</script>
```

Comment: It's missing the quote around the JavaScript string.

Comment: @TimWolla: he specifically asked for just using it, he didnt asked it to be string.

Comment: it could have been corrected with edit but i guess down vote is more easy thing instead of correction

Comment: @Doorknob: i just confirmed my Original Post `var test= <?php echo SITE_URL; ?>;` is not a syntax error. Please fiddle it i just checked it on my local

Comment: Now you've fixed it, by wrapping it in a string.

Comment: @Doorknob: yes i fixed that but what i quoted in above comment is the original syntax that i posted. And this is what i was referring to.